# how to display result in other text box with condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have field like this
[image]

as shown in figure, if i enter less than 20 in result field then the nor/ab value should be automaticaly changes as "low" if entered more than 110, should display high else normal.
so i just tried it by jquery and did not successed...let see my form.

```
<div style=" width:900px; height:auto; float:left; text-align:center;">
<div style=" height:auto; width:140px; float:left">{title}</div>
<div style=" height:30px; width:140px; float:left"><input type="text" height="30px" width="140" name="rep_result_{txt}"  /></div>
<div style=" height:30px; width:140px; float:left">{unit}</div>
<div style=" height:30px; width:140px; float:left">{first_val}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{last_val}</div>
<div style=" height:30px; width:140px; float:left"><input type="text" height="30px" width="140" name="remark_{txt}" >
```

you can see i entered range value in two section first_val(means 20) and last_val(means 110), so how can i use jquery to make it complete(remember range value is dynamic so i can't apply condition only on 20,110)...thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='result' />
<input type='text' id='nor' data-min='20' data-max='110' />
```

JavaScript

```
$('#result').change(function() {
    var result = $(this).val(),
        nor = $('#nor'),
        min = nor.data('min'),
        max = nor.data('max');
    if(result < min) {
        nor.val('Low');
    } else if (result < max) {
        nor.val('Normal');
    } else {
        nor.val('High');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BbPC7/

May be this can be helpful.

Comment: You can dynamically change data-min and data-max attributes with the required ones. Here I assumed only one row. Use classes instead of ids for this to work with multiple rows.

Comment: Used jQuery 1.9.1 in the above example.